# Error occurring when implementing NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am quite new to NodeJS so this task is my beginning steps to my NodeJS training. I am having a problem which I do not understand at all. A simple help would be great for me to move forward.

This is my code

```
var rect = {
perimeter: function (x,y) {
       return (2*(x+y));
},
area: function (x,y) {
        return (x*y);
}
};

function solveRect(l,b) {
console.log("Solving for rectangle with l = " + l + " and b = " + b);

if (l < 0 || b < 0) {
    console.log("Rectangle dimensions should be greater than zero:  l = " + l + ",  and b = " + b);
}
else {
console.log("The area of a rectangle of dimensions length = " + l + " and breadth = " + b + " is " + rect.area(l,b));
console.log("The perimeter of a rectangle of dimensions length = " + l + " and breadth = " + b + " is " + rect.perimeter(l,b));
}
}

solveRect(2,4);
solveRect(3,5);
solveRect(-3,5);
```

The error I am having is

```
console.log("The area of a rectangle of dimensions length = " + l + " and 
                                                                        ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
at node.js:968:3
```

Comment: Hm I cannot replicate this error. Are you sure you are running the correct version of your code? In NodeJS (or rather vanilla JS) you need to restart the server to see changes

Comment: I've run your code provided and it works fine

Comment: Did you copy this code from somewhere? Sometimes there are hidden characters copied with the actual content which are ILLEGAL. Happens in jsFiddle for example.

I think it was the Zero-width Space Character most of the time

Comment: I guess there are problems with the characters